# Having Trouble to start "SQL Server Management Studio"

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010

I had VS-2008 in my PC and it was working fine with SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005.
But when i upgrade my Visual Studio Version to 2010, SQL Server stops working. Now i have MS Visual Studio 2010 in my PC and it is working fine. But when i start SQL Server it Doesn't suggest me any Server name.
I think VS 2010 doesn't support SQL Server 2005.
How could i start SQL Server, can anybody please help me with that.

Comment: before I made my answer, a I guess that the VS2010 installer install you SQLServer 2008, so you have a conflict between instances, please run this query in a cmd prompt SQLCMD -L, it will list you all the instances of sql server installed in your machine.

Comment: It Display only this "Servers :"

Comment: You don't have an instance of SQLSERVER installed in that computer, ok. That doesn't answer the question because it have nothing to do with the fact that you can't start SSMS, i'm guessing here, I think you have a installation problem, maybe two different versions of SSManagment Studio. You should go to program files, I once have same problem.